# How to use root-relative URL's on Apache server without a domain name?

Tags: html, apache

I have a staging server (VPS) that has a dedicated IP address. For example, http://numeric.ip.address/

I can access the the files in the public_html folder by doing the usual tilda thing in the URL - http://numeric.ip.address/~account/

I have a folder I've developed locally that uses root-relative paths to resources, but 
when I load the file in the browser, those root-relative URL's jump up in the directory all the way to the root IP address, instead of the public_html folder /~account/.

I realize there are better ways to set up a staging server and I plan to do so in the future, but I'm facing a deadline where it would be really handy to make this work.

I've tried tossing a base href tag in header tags, but that isn't doing the trick.

Comment: Apache doesn't rewrite the contents of your HTML output.  If your `a` tags start with `/` then these are absolute links, and won't work if you're changing the site root.  You'd need to switch to using relative links, e.g. ones without a leading `/`.

Answer (score 0):

In Apache, normally you have "VirtualHost" container or .htaccess file. In it, you set your domain and DocumentRoot.
From what you describe, all you need to do is set your DocumenRoot correctly to you root of your site. then in the Browser, you can point to your paths. So if you have folder called "finance" and inside that folder you have document call "report1.pdf", you can put in your browser, example.com/finance/report1.pdf -as long as you have your DocumentRoot and site setup correctly and put the files in correct path, Apache will serve the file.

```
<VirtualHost 10.1.2.3>
  ServerName   example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com # not necessary
  DocumentRoot /www/docs/host.foo.com
  ...omitted the <Direcotry> </Directory> stuff

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: so if I have a machine with multiple accounts on the same IP, I'm putting a VirtualHost entry into the .htaccess file that is located inside the specific accounts' public_html file? I'm not seeing any VirtualHost in there by default.

Comment: Nope. if you're using .htaccess, you're already inside Directory container and can't put in VirtualHost. If you're using host company, just work with the .htaccess  file and set your DocumentRoot